# no related products in magento

Tags: magento

I have no products in the list where Magneto allows me to relate other products to the current product. Can anyone help me ? I have seen references to inventory but these are so old ( 3 years old ) that I assume that bug is not the source of my problem.

Comment: thanks that worked but have you any idea why the any/yes/no dropdown is defaulting to yes - i didnt think it used to be that way

Comment: wow - i think it's starting to look like intended behavior - why ? :-(

Comment: By default, view the products which are related. That's the logic. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select any in dropdown or clear your filters.
Default option is yes in order to help identify existing related products. I agree it would be better to display all products when you don't have related products yet.